# To response the query result with the equivalent performance as `psycopg2` does

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I try to explain my case clearly.

I want to use Ruby on Rails to response the query result with the equivalent performance as `psycopg2` does.

I  use `psycopg2` Python package to query my database (PostgreSQL),

No matter how many results in the response, (eg. 2 million)

I can get it much faster than in `Ruby on Rails` with JSON API.

```
    self.cur.execute(
        """
        SELECT * FROM products
        """
    for result in self.cur.fetchall():
          print(result)
```

I wonder how to  to make the similar behavior in Rails but not to be too slow.

I want to provider user a WEBAPI, such as `http://SERVER/get_users` then user can get the response in any format (I don't care what the format is. The faster the better)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails uses multi_json gem by default to render JSON, and multi_json uses several engines, being Oj one of the fastest.

If you want to render a set of records, you can do it like this in a controller:

```
render json: Product.all
```

But 2 million records is a huge amount of data, normally you would use pagination o some criteria to filter the results.

Comment: sorry, i tried it before it's too slow on rendering. I want to skip rendering process.